# How to open an activity on the last section of navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation-drawer

I have three buttons inside my activity. 
They all passing the user to the same activity, but each one of them, passing the user to a different section on the next activity's navigation drawer.

My question is how can I create an intent to a section of a navigation drawer on a different activity?

Comment: do you want to add one more option in your navigation drawer when user is in a Next Activity?

Comment: No. I want to know how to switch a section on navigation drawer.

Comment: ok, so basically you want that when the user clicks on a button in navigation drawer, it will take him/her to the specific section in next page. right???

Comment: This is exactly what I want @Devraj

Comment: Have you tried "ANCHOR LINKS"???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send a string or an Integer with an intent and check it `onResume()`

**(For Example):**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
  i.putExtra("StartFromAnotherActivity","start");    
  startActivity(intent);
```

Check if the received extra is equal to start in your onResume() then start the desired fragment.

**In your MainActivity which contains the drawer into onResume():**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String start = intent.getStringExtra("StartFromAnotherActivity");
if(start.equals("start")){
displayView(2);//int position of the desired fragment 
}
```

Comment: And how can I open the navigation drawer section?

Comment: there is a displayView() method in your MainActivity just fire it up when start=start check out my edited answer

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it later